# Opacity maps for THREE.js?

Tags: three.js

Are there any opacity maps for THREE.js ? Like:

[image]

so that I can use it on a map like

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`MeshBasicMaterial`, `MeshLambertMaterial`, `MeshPhongMaterial` and `MeshStandardMaterial` support an `alphaMap`.

Alternatively, you could bake the transparency into your color texture's alpha channel.

In either case, you need to set `material.transparent = true`.

EDIT: If you are implementing a cut-out (alpha is either 0 or 1), then instead of setting `material.transparent = true`, you can just set `material.alphaTest = 0.5`.

three.js r.87

Comment: @WestLangley Is this still the case? I noticed there is an alphaMap property now. Does that make this functionality built in?

Comment: Be sure to call ```material.needsUpdate = true;``` for the change to take effect.

Comment: @ranbuch Setting the `material.needsUpdate` flag is only required if the mesh has been previously rendered.

Comment: @WestLangley I don't know why buy it didn't work for me without ```needsUpdate = true```.